# Crosstab SPLITTING columns

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I would like to make a crosstab that can split when multiple details and not split when same detail is repeated

This example show that column 3 must be one case not 3 lines:
[image: This example show that column 3 must be one case not 3 lines]

is it possible to split a crosstab then bring lines together again ?

Comment: Are you asking about textFields with measures (not about column group)? Your question is unclear

Comment: i used only ROW-GROUP ( 3 row groups ) , is it possible that the third row does not split because it is the same like the first one  ??

Comment: Do you have same values at group?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/V7PmR

Comment: It should be one value because of grouping

Comment: how can i make the column number 3  works like column number 1 please ?

Comment: Does someone knows how to make the thirs COLUMN WORKING like the first COLUMN ???